# how to put an image inside a button? using html and css only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an image inside a button like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0P6c.png)

The code I have so far is:

`<button class="buttoni" style="width: 270px; height: 46.9px;">Earn Money Helping <b>People</b> <div><img src="img/pla.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25.7px; margin-left: 220px; margin-top: -50px;"> </div></button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<button class="buttoni" style="width: 270px; height: 46.9px;">Earn Money Helping <b>People</b><img src="img/pla.png" style="position: relative; float: right; width: 25px;"></button>
```

Adjust the height as needed for the image.

Are you just trying to learn HTML/CSS, I'd suggest putting the styling into a stylesheet rather than inline.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the icon using CSS instead. This would allow you to apply transitions / animations etc.

```css
.buttoni {
  width: 270px;
  height: 46.9px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
}

.buttoni:before,
.buttoni:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.buttoni:before {
  background: #29d4a2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
}

.buttoni:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #FFF;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  right: 20px;
  top: 19px;
}

.buttoni:hover {
  background: #29d4a2;
}

.buttoni:hover:before {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttoni">Earn Money Helping <b>People</b> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do it using html

```
<button class="buttoni" style="width: 270px; height: 46.9px;">Earn Money Helping <b>People</b><img src="img/pla.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25.7px; margin-left: 220px; margin-top: -50px;"></button>
```

Do not call div inside button because it is an erroneous form, since the button supports the insertion of images by default

In case you want to do it using CSS

> This should do do what you want, assuming your button image is 16 by 16 pixels.

```
.buttoni {
    background-image: url(/images/buttons/add.png); /* 16px x 16px */
    background-color: transparent; /* make the button transparent */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* make the background image appear only once */
    background-position: 0px 0px;  /* equivalent to 'top left' */
    border: none;           /* assuming we don't want any borders */
    cursor: pointer;        /* make the cursor like hovering over an <a> element */
    height: 16px;           /* make this the size of your image */
    padding-left: 16px;     /* make text start to the right of the image */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align the text vertically centered */
}
```